# How to alter how sort criteria displays

Tags: search

I have a search field that sorts based on title when the user begins to type. This is fine for the search but I want to display the content type in the dropdown as well. As of now it only displays the title. Can the content type be appended to the title and if so where?

Comment: Can you share some more information? What kind of Search are you using, regular Drupal, Solr, etc? Do you want Content type information (name?) to be a separate filter, or are you asking about the suggestion list that pops up when you type into autocomplete field? Maybe some screenshots would help to clarify.

Comment: I am talking about the suggestion that appears when typing into an autocomplete field. Currently the suggestions display the title but I would also like them to display the content type as well next to the title. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the autocomplete field coming from? Is it a Views Exposed Filter, site Search or something else?

Comment: Looking into it more it is an inline entity form field. Ideally I would like to hook the field and alter the autocomplete matches for it.